# How to merge 2 branches in git keeping the changes only from one branch

Tags: git

I have two branches. One is `master`, and the other one i `myBranch` and they look something like this:

```
master
   |
   |  myBranch
   |  /
   | /
   |/
   |
```

I want to merge them into one branch, keeping all the changes from the `master` branch, not keeping anything from `myBranch`.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, - and that I have had the same problem, but the way you've written your question, it sounds as if the answer is "keep master and throw away myBranch" ....

Comment: That sounds like just keeping the `master` branch and deleting `myBranch`.

Comment: If you don't want the changes in `myBranch` why doing a `merge`?

Comment: Yes I want to keep `master` but I don't want to delete `myBranch` because I'm using the same branch for another project (this was stupid idea, right?)

Comment: Sounds like your wanting to create a new repo for `myBranch` first and then delete `myBranch` from this repo?

Answer (score 9):

Merge the branch using the `ours` merge strategy:

```
git checkout -b new-branch master
git merge -s ours myBranch
```

Note that this is quite different from the `-X ours`, as initially stated in Koraktor's answer. `-X ours` is an option to the `recursive` strategy, which would still keep all changes from `myBranch`, but prefer resolutions from master **in case of conflict**. `-s ours`, on the other hand, completely ignores changes introduced by `myBranch`.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the branch:
`git branch -d "myBranch"`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ git merge -s ours myBranch
```

If you want this to happen directly on `master`, just omit the first command.

PS: "user4815162342" is right, I meant `-s` not `-X`.